# How to refer to bean in parent context from java config

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have two ApplicationContexts, one parent, one child.

In both, I have defined two beans: `prefix` and `suffix`. Both also have a full title bean made of `prefix` and `suffix` information. So far so good.
Now, I want to refer to `parent.suffix` bean from the child context, how can I do it?

Parent application context:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ParentCtx {

    @Bean
    String prefix() {
        return "Monsieur";
    }

    @Bean
    String suffix() {
        return "Senior";
    }

    @Bean
    public FullTitle raymond(String prefix, String suffix) {
        return new FullTitle(prefix, "Raymond", suffix);
    }
}
```

Child application context:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ChildCtx {

    @Bean
    public String prefix() {
        return "Damoiseau";
    }

    @Bean
    public String suffix() {
        return "Junior";
    }

    @Bean
    public FullTitle jean(String prefix, String suffix) {
        return new FullTitle(prefix, "Jean", suffix);
    }

    @Bean
    public FullTitle oldMartin(String prefix, String suffix) { // HERE: I want to refer to parent context suffix. how do you do???
        return new FullTitle(prefix, "Martin", suffix);
    }
}
```

The application:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext;

public class HierarchicalCtxApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (
                AnnotationConfigApplicationContext parentCtx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ParentCtx.class);
                GenericApplicationContext childCtx = new GenericApplicationContext(parentCtx)) {

            AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader rdr = new AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader(childCtx);
            rdr.register(ChildCtx.class);
            childCtx.refresh();

            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------ Full titles");
            System.out.println(childCtx.getBean("jean", FullTitle.class).fullTitle());
            System.out.println(childCtx.getBean("raymond", FullTitle.class).fullTitle());
            System.out.println(childCtx.getBean("oldMartin", FullTitle.class).fullTitle());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't as for the context sake you are actually overriding this with a new prefix and suffix. Also do you really have 2 contexts or do you have 2 configuration classes. Finally defining things like a `String` as a bean (or anyother primitive) is generally just a bad idea.

Comment: Actually it is not entirely true what I wrote. You could inject the `ParentCtx` class and call the methods on there to retrieve the needed prefixes (instead of using `String prefix, String suffix` in your method you would use `ParentCtx parent` and then use `parent.suffix()` to get the proper one.

Comment: I added client code to clarify things a bit. I'm aware of the solution involving ParentCtx injection, however it is not ideal since clientctx must know of parentctx. What I look for is an indication to the dependency injection to look in parent context (if that exists).

Also, yes, declaring String beans is bad, that's for example purposes.

Comment: Without an `@Qualifier` you cannot. If this is for sample purposes, then include a proper sample and not a dumbed down version. Either way your client/child needs to know the `@Qualifier`, so either way it needs to know something. But there is no direct reference/instruction to tell look in the parent (which parent as there could be a complete hierarchy, where to stop?).

Comment: Ok, good to know. I was afraid I was missing something since you can do that in xml configuration within `constructor-arg` tag using `<ref parent="beanName" />`